# AWS returning a private object, how can I make it public?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, private

I'm trying to use `AWS Rekognition` to get all the labels in a photo but in return I get a **private object** with the arrays containing the labels.

My question is: **How do I make the object public so that I can access it?**

**My code :**

```
<?php

$result = $client->detectLabels([
    'Image' => [ 
        'Bytes' => file_get_contents("Photo.jpg"),   
    ],
    'MinConfidence' => 90,
]);

print_r($result);
```

The output is a private object like this one :

```
Aws\Result Object
(
    [data:Aws\Result:private] => Array
    (
        [Labels] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Name] => Text
                        [Confidence] => 99.841453552246
             ...
```

Comment: There might be a method for retrieving data in the result object. Have tried seeing what ```print_r(get_class_methods($result))``` gives? The docs say there is at least a ```get ( string $key )``` method in ```Aws\Result```

Comment: You could also use ```\ReflectionClass``` to achieve something like what you're asking, though it will not be the most efficient way of getting at the juicy data. Check out ```\ReflectionClass```, its ```getProperty``` method and ```setAccessible``` method for the property.

Comment: Thanks, that get ( string $key ) method worked.